# History of business calculus/linear algebra curriculum

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I will be teaching a combination of business calculus and business linear algebra, two classes that have been around awhile at my school. I’m assuming people are familiar with these types of classes. I’m wondering if anyone can tell me a couple topics that were classically in these classes that were probably discarded over time, and a couple topics that either have been added to more modern forms of the classes, or SHOULD be added.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the contents of the course, or the country or even university where it takes place? I would not assume business calculus and linear algebra look the same all of the world. I guess these are university courses?

Comment: What does "a combination of" mean? They're not trying to cram both of these into a single one-semester course, are they?

Comment: It sure sounds like it. Two-headed monster?